# How to display the current month in FTL code?

Tags: java, freemarker

How can I print the current month in a ftl file?

Comment: What is the application you are trying to use FTLs for (Hibernate reverse engineering, etc)?  What have you tried so far?  A little more information would likely help a lot in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a configuration already, and you are doing something like this to process it:

```
Template template = config.getTemplate("template.ftl");
Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
model.put("currentDate", new Date());
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
template.process(model, writer);
```

You can reference your date in template.ftl by doing something like this:

```
Today's date is ${currentDate?string("MMMM")}!
```

The `MMMM` part can be any string using the SimpleDateFormat syntax

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know (and cannot find directly) what FTL is, so please don't kill me if this is not what you want.

But: To get the current month you can use GregorianCalendar:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
int month = gc.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the current month.

```
<#assign currentMonth =  .now?string("MMMM") />
```